# Converting .rhtml views to .html.erb, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rake, partials, rhtml

In migrating an old Rails app to 2.3.10, I ran across [this blog post](http://thelucid.com/2007/05/16/rails-edge-getting-your-view-extensions-ready-for-edge/) that has a nice rake task to convert `.rhtml` files to `.html.erb`, `.rjs` to `.js.rjs`, `.haml` to `.html.haml`, etc. However, when I ran it I found that the partials hadn't be updated, because the regex in the rake task skips partials when doing the conversions.

In the blog post comments, someone mentions that the new naming scheme doesn't work for partials, which is why the regex is the way it is. Does anyone know what he's referring to? Was this a bug that was around for a while in edge Rails but then corrected?

Comment: Perhaps? Why does it matter if it's not the case that partials don't work, now?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything and there wasn't another reason why partials shouldn't be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments below that one, another mentions the revision where that issue was fixed.